# Speed in a java 2d game

Tags: java, graphics, pixel

I got a game where every 15 milliseconds, a ball moves 1 pixel in a direction.

If I wanted to cut it's speed in half, what would I do? Pixels can't be floats, can they?

Thanks

Comment: Change the time to 30 milliseconds...

Comment: the 15 milliseconds period applies to the entire game. So changing it to 30 will also make other object move slower.

Comment: Assuming that the ball's movement is the smallest unit of movement, you could half the rest of objects movement quantities...

Comment: In general, is it a better idea to manage very object speed independently? Not sure yet how to do that, but somebody here suggested that the way I made the game (a way that I saw in lots of places on the web) is a bad idea, and I should manage everything's speed the same way. Do you agree?

Comment: A lot comes down to how you want to handle things, but personally, I would work around the time being the main factor, this allows you to adjust the speed by adjusting the timing...but that's just me...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would normally store the ball's precise position as a float, but round the coordinates to integers when you are drawing.

So: give the ball class some kind of float-coordinate member (eg. Point2D.Float or two floats), update your paint method to round this coordinates and draw the ball there.

The result enables you to give the ball any speed you like.

If you give us some code, we might also help you with implementation.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I'll try this and post here wether it worked or didn't.